# NullPointerException Warning on getView() inside onActivityCreated/onStart/onViewCreated method

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nullpointerexception, getview

I know `getView()` might return null inside `onCreateView()` method, but even if I put the below code inside `onActivityCreated()`, `onStart()` or `onViewCreated()` methods, it still shows the warning about a possible `NullPointerException` in Android Studio (although my program runs without any issue). How to get rid of this warning?

I am using Fragments.

Code:

```
datpurchased = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.datepurchased); 
//datpurchased defined as instance variable in the class
```

Warning:

> Method invocation 'getView().findViewById(R.id.datepurchased)' may
>   produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Android Studio is based on IntelliJ IDEA, and this is a feature of IntelliJ that gives you warnings at compile time when you are not checking if an object returned by a method is `null` before using it.

One way to avoid this is program in the style that always checks for `null` or catches `NullPointerException`, but it can get very verbose, especially for things you know will always return an object and never `null`.

Another alternative is to suppress the warnings on such cases using annotations such as `@SuppressWarnings` for methods that use objects you know can never be null:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"NullableProblems"})
public Object myMethod(Object isNeverNull){
    return isNeverNull.classMethod();
}
```

or, in your case, a line-level suppression:

```
//noinspection NullableProblems
datpurchased = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.datepurchased); //datpurchased defined as instance variable in the class
```

Be sure that the objects really can never be null, though.

More information on IntelliJ's @NotNull and @Nullable annotations can be found [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/howto.html), and more about inspections and supressing them [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/suppressing-inspections.html).

Comment: I was able to suppress my warning with `noinspection ConstantConditions`. But the link about suppressing inspections was very useful!