# Avoiding != null using a method in java

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

In my example below I want to avoid writing getView != null every time I want to use getView. To keep it cleaner I create a method hasView() which does the check for me. However I still get a warning. Is there any way around this?

```
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

public void showView(){
    if(hasView()){
        getView().show(); // Shows warning Method invocation 'showLoading' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'
    }
}


boolean hasView(){
    return getView() != null;
}

@Nullable
private View getView(){
    return view;
}
```

I am using Android Studio/IntelliJ. I know that I can use @SuppressWarnings [I have seen this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30113709/nullpointerexception-warning-on-getview-inside-onactivitycreated-onstart-onvie) but this makes the code uglier.

Comment: And sorry, what is your question?

Comment: Where is showLoading() ?

Comment: What does your app do when the view is null? If it was not possible to fetch/ retrieve the view I would think about stopping the application and report the issue.

Comment: @GhostCat Sorry. My question was how can I avoid the warning and write cleaner code.

Comment: @StefanFreitag I just used getView as an example. It could have been any method that returned a null object.

Comment: Ah, ok I understand. Then you should go for the Optional.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I  want to avoid writing getView != null every time I want to use
>   getView ?

You can use **Null Object pattern** to avoid checking for `!= null` everywhere in the program, the code is shown below:

**(1) Define an EmptyView Class**

```
   public EmptyView {

     //Define a static emptyView, so that we can reuse the same object
     public static final EmptyView emptyView = new EmptyView();

     public show() {
         //does nothing
      }
    }
```

**(2) Use the EmptyView in case of no view available:**

```
    //other classes:
    private View getView(){
        if(viewAvailable) {
           return view;
        } else {
            return EmptyView.emptyView;
        }  
    }

    public void showView(){
        getView().show();
    }
```

You can look at Wiki [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) more info & Java example.

When you return `null` from various methods, they will potentially cause the `NullPointerException` in the programs and will become very hard to debug in larger projects.

So, it is a bad practice to return `null` from methods (& they should be avoided) and that is the reason Spring API generally return empty `list`/`set` objects (instead of `null`) while trying to retrieve data from `DAO`/`Repository` classes (like `EmptyView` object as explained above).

**P.S.:** This option works with and without Java8. 
If you are using Java8, then prefer to do with `Optional` as given in the answer from @janos

Comment: Thanks. I am not using Java8 so I will have to use this pattern. Only annoying thing is that every time I add a method to the View I have to  update it to EmptyView as well.

Comment: Can you tell me an example method like what you need to add ?

Comment: Good suggestion.  You might also avoid doing "new EmptyView() "  if you define a static instance of EmptyView.  Since it is "empty",  it is immutable by definition and there's no side effect in reusing it.

Comment: @javaguy I meant that if I add have say getView().hide() or getView().foo() then I will have to add these to the EmptyView as well.

Comment: @Insac Thanks for your suggestion, added the static instance to reuse

Comment: @UbaierBhat you are right, to avoid null checks at multiple places, we need to do this in only one single place

Answer (score 4):

You might be interested in using an [`Optional`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Optional.html), added in API level 24 of Android, for example:

```
private Optional<View> getView() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(view);
}

public void showView() {
    getView().ifPresent(View::show);
}
```

Comment: The optional was the first I had in mind and  learned by your answer that it is available in Android :)

Comment: Thanks this is nice but unfortunately I am not using Java8 for my current project. But I will definitely use it in the future. :)